# Arrays in inline assembly stuck on first two values

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

The objective of the program is to do an insertion sort in X86 assembly via inline assembly in C in Visual Studio.  The problem is that it will only swap the first two numbers in the array.  Here is the code would be grateful if anyone could help?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

// Function prototypes //
int isort(char* data, int size);
static void print_data(const char* array, int size);

// Global variables //
char* iarray;

int main()
{
    //iarray = malloc(SIZE); // Allocate memory for the array //
     int iarray[100] = { 8,5, 12, 10, 56, 22, 98, 120, 90, 4, 349, 8, 45, 37, 43, 67, 3, 18, 97, 71 };
        // Load the integer array with data to sort //
        /*iarray[0] = 5;
    iarray[1] = 8;
    iarray[2] = 12;
    iarray[3] = 10;
    iarray[4] = 56;
    iarray[5] = 22;
    iarray[6] = 98;
    iarray[7] = 120;
    iarray[8] = 90;
    iarray[9] = 4;
    iarray[10] = 349;
    iarray[11] = 8;
    iarray[12] = 45;
    iarray[13] = 37;
    iarray[14] = 43;
    iarray[15] = 67;
    iarray[16] = 3;
    iarray[17] = 18;
    iarray[18] = 97;
    iarray[19] = 17;*/

    //print_data(iarray, SIZE); // Display the unsorted array //
        isort(iarray, SIZE); // Sort the array //
        //print_data(iarray, SIZE); // Display the sorted array //
        getchar();
        free(iarray); // Free memory //

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


//*****************************************************************************//
// isort //
//*****************************************************************************//
int isort(int* data, int arr_size)
{
    arr_size = arr_size - 1;
    __asm
    {
    mov esi, 0
    mov eax, data
    mov edx, 0
    aloop:
    mov ebx, [eax+edx]
        mov ecx, [eax+edx+4]
        mov [eax+edx+4], ebx
        mov[eax+edx], ecx
        cmp esi, 12
        add esi,1
        add edx,4
        jae loopend
        jmp aloop

    loopend:
    }
    int y = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < SIZE; z++) {
        y = data[z];
        printf("%d", y);
        printf(" ");
    }

}

static void print_data(int array, int size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", iarray[i]);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```

When executed it prints: 5 8 12 10 56 22 98 120 90 4 349 8 45 37 43 67 3 18 97 71
From the array: 8,5, 12, 10, 56, 22, 98, 120, 90, 4, 349, 8, 45, 37, 43, 67, 3, 18, 97, 71

Comment: Won't `add esi,1` `add edx,4` clobber the flags set by `cmp esi, 12` mucking up your conditional branches? I'd step through your code with a debugger. Visual Studio - even the free one) has a nice debugger that would allow you to step through the _C_ code an the inline assembly. You may discover your own bugs.

Comment: jae / jmp could be replaced with jnae (aka jb).  You already have the loop-exit conditional branch at the bottom of the loop...

Comment: I second the comments above. But there is another question that necessarily arose: where is your insertion code? You are swapping bytes and checking for the end of the array, but where do you _insert_ values? Insertion sort without insertion seems a little bit incomplete...

Comment: Thanks Michael, Peter and zx485.  I got past the swapping issue it did clobber the flags.